# Codeigniter on subdomain linking stylesheets and javascripts

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I was previously having some mod_rewrite errors, with a simple ;,

Well this has been resolved.
So again the structure, I have a codeigniter application on a subdomain. eg.
test.site.com

https-vhost.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
    ServerName test.localhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess file located in the base folder of my application, (htdocs/test/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.localhost.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-_]+).localhost.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/ [P]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.text|css|js)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So, i am able to load the CI_controllers now, however, I seem to be unable to link any style sheets or javascript files.

These files are located in an Assets folder like so

```
htdocs
  |-test
  |  |-application
  |  |-assets
  |  |  |-css
  |  |  |  |-style.css
  |  |  |-js
  |  |  |  |-jquery.js
```

even with a full site link, I cannot seem to load these files,

```
Request URL: http://test.localhost.com/assets/css/style.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

Do I need to create specific routings for this as well?

Comment: Try Assets with a capital A in your URL.

Comment: sorry thats my typo, everything is in lower case,

Answer (score 0):

Try either excluding the assets directory or anything ending in css/js:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.text|css|js|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

or:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.text|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the an answer my apologies.

Code Igniter is a little special, at any rate, here is the mod rewrite I am using, and having no issues with now.

```
# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # mod_rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine on

    # The RewriteBase of the system (if you are using this sytem in a sub-folder).
    # RewriteBase /

    # This will make the site only accessible without the "www." 
    # (which will keep the subdomain-sensive config file happy)
    # If you want the site to be accessed WITH the "www." 
    # comment-out the following two lines.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.localhost\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # If a controler can't be found - then issue a 404 error from PHP
    # Error messages (via the "error" plugin)
    # ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/403/
    # ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/404/
    # ErrorDocument 500 /index.php/500/

    # Deny any people (or bots) from the following sites: (to stop spam comments)
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} nienschanz\.ru [NC,OR]
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} porn\.com
    # RewriteRule .* - [F]
    # Note: if you are having trouble from a certain URL just 
    # add it above to forbide all visitors from that site.

    # You can also uncomment this if you know the IP:
    # Deny from 192.168.1.1

    # If the file is NOT the index.php file
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    # Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
    # RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

    # If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```